# How to fix "ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output)." on CentOS?

Tags: ruby, centos, rvm

After `rvm` installation on CentOS 5.8:

```
[rails@localhost ~]$ rvm -v
rvm 1.16.17
[rails@localhost ~]$ which ruby
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby
[rails@localhost ~]$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [i686-linux]
[rails@localhost ~]$ which gem
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/gem
```

there is a warning:

```
$ gem -v
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
1.8.24
```

I followed [some advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791960/libyaml-error-install-rails-with-rubygems):

```
$ rvm pkg install libyaml
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /home/rails/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /home/rails/.rvm/src
Prepare yaml in /home/rails/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Configuring yaml in /home/rails/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Compiling yaml in /home/rails/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Installing yaml to /home/rails/.rvm/usr

Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force
```

and then:

```
$ rvm reinstall all --force
Removing /home/rails/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p371...
Removing /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371...
No binary rubies available for: centos/5.8/i386/ruby-1.8.7-p371.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.8.7-p371 - #downloading ruby-1.8.7-p371, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.8.7-p371 - #extracting ruby-1.8.7-p371 to /home/rails/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p371
ruby-1.8.7-p371 - #extracted to /home/rails/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p371
Applying patch /home/rails/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.7/stdout-rouge-fix.patch
Applying patch /home/rails/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.7/no_sslv2.diff
ruby-1.8.7-p371 - #configuring
ruby-1.8.7-p371 - #compiling
ruby-1.8.7-p371 - #installing 
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.8.24 for ruby-1.8.7-p371 ...
Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
Saving wrappers to '/home/rails/.rvm/bin'.
ruby-1.8.7-p371 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
ruby-1.8.7-p371 - #importing default gemsets (/home/rails/.rvm/gemsets/)
Install of ruby-1.8.7-p371 - #complete 
Please be aware that you just installed a ruby that requires 2 patches just to be compiled on up to date linux system.
This may have known and unaccounted for security vulnerabilities.
Please consider upgrading to Ruby 1.9.3-286 which will have all of the latest security patches.
Making gemset ruby-1.8.7-p371 pristine.
Making gemset ruby-1.8.7-p371@global pristine.
Removing /home/rails/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286...
Removing /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286...
No binary rubies available for: centos/5.8/i386/ruby-1.9.3-p286.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p286, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p286 to /home/rails/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #extracted to /home/rails/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #configuring
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #compiling
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #installing 
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.8.24 for ruby-1.9.3-p286 ...
Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
Saving wrappers to '/home/rails/.rvm/bin'.
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #importing default gemsets (/home/rails/.rvm/gemsets/)
Install of ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #complete 
Making gemset ruby-1.9.3-p286 pristine.
Making gemset ruby-1.9.3-p286@global pristine.
```

Too bad, the warning is still there:

```
$ gem -v
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
1.8.24
```

How can I get rid of the warning?

UPDATE: (applying `rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --movable`)

```
$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --movable
Removing /home/rails/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286...
Removing /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286...
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /home/rails/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /home/rails/.rvm/src
Prepare yaml in /home/rails/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Configuring yaml in /home/rails/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Compiling yaml in /home/rails/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Installing yaml to /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p286, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p286 to /home/rails/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286
ruby-1.9.3-p286 - #extracted to /home/rails/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p286
Applying patch /home/rails/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/ruby-multilib.patch
Error running 'patch -F 25 -p1 -N -f -i /home/rails/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/ruby-multilib.patch', please read /home/rails/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p286/patch.apply.ruby-multilib.log
There has been an error applying the specified patches. Halting the installation.
Making gemset ruby-1.9.3-p286 pristine.
Making gemset ruby-1.9.3-p286@global pristine.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After `rvm pkg install libyaml`, reinstall ruby 1.9.3 by:

```
 rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-libyaml-dir=/home/rails/.rvm/usr
```

*credit:* https://stackoverflow.com/a/12882906/88597

Comment: based on the error message you're getting (`To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.`) this *should* fix your problem.  My personal experience with rvm has been that it's a world of pain and suffering though so your mileage may vary :-)

Comment: Finally, thankyou! I've "rvm pkg install libyaml; rvm reinstall 1.9.3"'d a hundred times.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install libtool
sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

I've tried all, this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
rvm get head
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --movable
```

Comment: "There has been an error applying the specified patches. Halting the installation." (See UPDATE in question)

Comment: updated my answer - you need to get newer rvm first

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to install the libyaml:

```
$ wget http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz 
$ tar xzvf yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz 
$ cd yaml-0.1.4 
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local 
$ make 
$ make install
```

refer to: http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/10/31/install-ruby-193-with-libyaml-on-centos/

Comment: I am installing rubies via rvm at user level, not system-wide.

Comment: you have to make sure your OS has libyaml installed, no matter if the RVM is installed at user level or system-wide. and, if you don't have `sudo` access, just modify the `--prefix` parameter, and then install rvm with additional parameters.

Comment: libyaml is installed by `rvm pkg install libyaml`, as shown in question.

Comment: I want to say that you have to install the 'libyaml' by `yum` or `make`, but not `rvm pkg install`.

Comment: after installing `libyaml` and then `rvm reinstall 1.9.3`, the warning is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You can install libyaml-devel from alternative repository (I used repoforge.org):

```
sudo rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
sudo rpm -ivh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
sudo yum install -y libyaml-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

As windows user, this worked for me.

```
gem install yaml
```

And uninstall `ruby` and reinstall